# How to show DIV that follows position of text cursor (caret) in a textarea?

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea, caret

See image.  I presume this would be possible in jquery where a floating div can be displayed relative to the text cursor |

I've found options for relation to the mouse pointer, but can't find for "text cursor/caret/text insertion cursor".  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Take a look at [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter) How to show tooltips with `::after` pseudo-selector.